# Laravel validate() function is changing keys inside array

Tags: php, laravel

I have a form that populates elements dynamically from a set of parameters (ID, name, type, etc) and I give the name of every element its ID ($parameter->id).

The problem I'm facing at the moment is that I'm doing validation for every input, and I've got the correct array to send to validate() function, as you can see in the first image, but the function is changing the keys (ids) I've got inside them inside the validation function.

[image]

[image]

First picture is the array I send to validate().
Second picture is the view ErrorBag, and as you can see, it changes the 2 I had previously to a 0, all the others work perfectly.

I've tried changing the keys to string like the others that work, but I haven't been able to do it and I don't know if its possible

Comment: Can you put your `$request->input()` and your `validate` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand, so your problem is not with the validate method but with the declaration of the array. In php the array keys can be of different types and even mix types as you did. However it is not a good idea as many things can go wrong.
In your case, there is this difference between key (string) and key (int) the array automatically converts to the beginning of the index that starts at 0. Therefore, if you have:

```
[
'key1' => something,
'key2' => semething else,
'5' => another,
'key3' => another
'8' => another,
7 => another
];
```

The resulting array will be:

```
[
0 => another,
'key1' => something,
'key2' => semething else,
'key2' => another
'8' => another,
7 => another
];
```

This is because position 0 of your array is occupied with the index, nicknamed, key1. In the worst case, it will overwrite the array index.

Try to define indexes with only one type or integer or string. If not, for your case. See in the documentation how the array will be treated for its definition of keys.

https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.types.array.php

https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/types.comparisons.php

Comment: Thanks! I knew something like this was the problem, but I'm new to PHP. Ended up adding a prefix for each input, so they're all string. Have a good day!

Comment: you are welcome. We are here for that. You will probably help me with other questions ahhahaha. Good work for you.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using validate () -> method, why don't you use a create a form request?

like that :

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class ClienteFormRequest extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'cadNome' => 'required',
            'cadCPF' => 'nullable',
            'cadEmail' => 'nullable|email',
            'cadEmailSec' => 'nullable|email',
            'cadTel' => 'nullable|digits_between:10,11',
            'cadTelSec' => 'nullable|digits_between:10,11'
        ];
    }
}
```

you can create it with the command

php artisan make:request "request name"

and instead of forwarding a generic request to the controller and validating it there. send the custom request to the controller

exemple :

```
public function store(ClienteFormRequest $request,CriadorDeCliente $criadorDeCliente)
{
    $cliente = $criadorDeCliente->criarCliente(
        $request->cadNome,$request->cadCPF,
        $request->cadOBS,
        [$request->cadEmail,$request->cadEmailSec],
        [$request->cadTel,$request->cadTelSec]
    );
 }
```

Comment: Firstly, thank you. I did it, but the error persists, probably the validate() function is called internally with the rules array, in the custom form request. The problem occurs in the input's whose name is of type int.

Comment: I undestood. I'm will answer again, because my response is too long for a comment. :P